# Configuring Nlog for asp.net core 2.02

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, nlog

I am trying to get NLog working in my asp.net core web api 2 which returns json but I am wanting to get loggin in for tracing use etc.

I have setup my nlog.config as per below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}\logs\GDStationaryNetCore\${shortdate}.log"
            encoding="utf-8"
            layout="[${longdate}][${machinename}][${level}] ${message} ${exception}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then I changed my configure section in my startup to be as follows.

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, LoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");


    // make sure Chinese chars don't fk up
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

            //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            //add NLog.Web
            app.AddNLogWeb();

            //needed for non-NETSTANDARD platforms: configure nlog.config in your project root. NB: you need NLog.Web.AspNetCore package for this.         
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

            app.UseMvc();
}
```

But When I try to compile it gives the following

> app.AddNLogWeb(); is obseleet use use UseNLog instead

But when i try to find  it on the app. it is not there hope someone can help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AddNLogWeb is obsolete in nlog

see: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/44f29fe12569846fa784f20a34726b82ade6526b/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/AspNetExtensions.cs#L29

use UseNLog:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
        .Build();
```

Comment: Hi Alex where should this build host go?

Comment: See your program.cs

Comment: may seem like a dumb question, but what about the "nlog.config" file, you are not pointing it

Comment: You can load config from place you like:

`NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration("nlog.config");`